# PQL package to convert SQL query to MongoDB query

Tags: python, sql, mongodb

Using pql (https://github.com/alonho/pql) package to convert SQL query to MondoDB query and could successfully pull data.

```
>>> import pql
>>> pql.find("a > 1")
{'a': {'$gt': 1}}
```

**Does anyone know how to use pql to convert a query which has time limit?**
 Example:

```
2020-02-01> time_column > 2020-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue is following:

```
>>> pql.find('a == 1', schema={'a': pql.DateTimeField()})
{'a': datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 16, 0, 1)}
```